# Save auto incrementing id / counter in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a way to set the id (or a counter) in the pre or post save middleware?

I'd like to have a running auto increment that stores the latest index of a document.
In my case whenever I save a new page (no update!), I need the id (or a counter) to start with 0 and increasing with each new page.

I've tried both pre and post middlewares in which I set the id and also the _id directly to the number of existing pages. However, Mongoose preserves its automatically generated id and doesn't allow it to be overwritten.

Also I'm not able to set the value to a field like 'counter' in the pre or post middleware.
Obviously, I'm doing something totally wrong.

Sadly the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) does not provide any enlightening example.
Please help.

(Side note: I don't want to update the id/counter manually in a following update. Neither do I want the client code to provide a counter variable. The save logic needs to figure this out on its own.)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { updateIfCurrentPlugin } from 'mongoose-update-if-current'

interface PageDoc extends mongoose.Page {
    counter: number
    name: string

// An interface that describes the properties that are required to create a new Page.
interface PageAttrs {
    name: string
}

interface PageModel extends mongoose.Model<PageDoc> {
    build(attrs: PageAttrs): PageDoc
}

const PageSchema = new mongoose.Schema<PageDoc>(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    {
        toJSON: {
            transform(doc, ret) {
                // modify ret directly
                ret.id = ret._id
                delete ret._id
                //delete ret.__v //versionKey: false,
            }
        }
    }
)

PageSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
    const existingPages = await Page.find({})

    this.set('id', existingPages.length)
    next()
})

PageSchema.set('versionKey', 'version')
PageSchema.plugin(updateIfCurrentPlugin)

PageSchema.statics.build = (attrs: PageAttrs) => {
    //const existingPages = await Page.find({})

    let symbol = new Page({
        name: attrs.name
    })

    console.log('Returning page with id ', symbol.id)

    return symbol
}

const Page = mongoose.model<PageDoc, PageModel>('Page', PageSchema)

export { Page }
```

Answer (score 1):

idt you need `middleware` for it, it will cause issue if some users creating page in the same time

and keep `_id` as it is, use `counter` instead

to count all the documents, use `count()

the code would be like:

```
const counter = await Page.countDocuments({});

const data = new Page({
       counter: counter
        name: attrs.name
    })
await Page.save()
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to have client code (e.g. a 'new' route) to handle the query on its own just like your solution shows, but instead provide that solution wrapped nicely within a middleware. However, thanks, your solution is a some sort of last resort. :)